# Ruby Client-Server application structure

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm about to begin a reasonable pure ruby project becoming from a Java and C background, and with some experience with Rails.

I'm looking for some advices with what's the best packaging/arrangement practice for a distributed ruby application that basically consists in Client app and the Server app.

The client only talks with the server to receive/send objects (json, and others) and to upload and download files, all from network. The server will deal with the local or remote storing of all files and store simple information (db).

I already read a lot about these and I found and know the best practices for a simple gem, like:

```
- appname/
- bin/ 
- lib/
    - appname.rb 
    - appname/
        - (appname::classes)
- test/ 
- readme, etc
```

But what about a reasonable big client-server app like these (2 app's in the same project)?

It's best/common to suit that in two gems? Or make them in same gem in different modules?

Do you know some ruby open source project/gem with a structure like these (client and server app) that I can go and see it's choices?

Sorry for the question size, i'm looking for this so I can define a good structure right now and avoid problems when the code begins to grow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best example that comes to my mind at this moment is [picky](http://florianhanke.com/picky/). It's a very well-done project. It's worth taking a look at it for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks thats gonna be useful :)

It would be great to have some more answers if anyone else can help.